# how to encode string to utf8 inside html

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, character-encoding, mailmerge

I'm trying to use awdeoroi mailmerge. In the html template i have french encoded characters in paragraph tags.
When i execute the mailing i have encoding errors :

```
UnicodeDecodeError : 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf4 in position 81: invalid continuation byte
```

How to encode those paragraph so that they are well treated in python ?

```
TO: {{email}}
SUBJECT: Testing mailmerge
FROM: My Self <myself@mydomain.com>
Content-Type: text/html

<html>
<body>

<p>Hi, {{name}},</p>

<p>Your number is {{number}}.</p>

<p>Sent by <a href="https://github.com/awdeorio/mailmerge">Here is the paragraph. Ce texte est en francais. <b>Accentué<b>. L'ideal</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your "mail" doesn't seem to be UTF-8. Discover what encoding it is, and so threat it accordly. But on email, better to use html entities, not the direct character.

Comment: to detect the character encoding of a byte string, have a look at [chardet](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hex `f4` is latin1 for `ô`.  If this was typed into Python, you needed this at the start of the source file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

If the data is coming from a database, please provide some more details.

If the text is coming from somewhere else, please provide some more details.